# Functional Interface that has Consumer with variable type

Tags: java, anonymous-types, consumer, functional-interface

I'm writing a Spring RowMapper, and I have a switch statement that checks each column label.  When the label matches, I get the value and set it in my return object.

If the value in the column is null, I do not want to initialize or set the value in my return object.

I've created some helper functions to do all this in one action:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface CallSetter<P1, P2, C1, R>
{
    public R exec(ResultSet rs, String columnLabel, Consumer<R> setter) throws SQLException;


}
```

This works fine when I define my different types as follows (one example):

```
CallSetter<ResultSet, String, Consumer<String>, String> setStr = (rs, columnLabel, setter) ->
{
    String val = rs.getString( columnLabel  );
    Boolean result = rs.wasNull();

    if( result == false )
        setter.accept( val );       

    return val;
};
```

However, I really want my Consumer to be anonymous in the functional interface, but then define the type in my definition, because I want all of my setX methods to return Boolean and not the value.  In other words, I want the Consumer to be able to define the type when I implement the interface so I can have a setStr, setDouble, etc.

When I try to do this (I'm just now learning Java 8, so I don't know if this is the correct syntax for what I'm trying to do):

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface CallSetter<P1, P2, C1, R>
{
    public R exec(ResultSet rs, String columnLabel, Consumer<?> setter) throws SQLException;


}
```

Then define my function(s) like this:

```
CallSetter<ResultSet, String, Consumer<String>, String> setStr = (rs, columnLabel, setter) ->
{
    String val = rs.getString( columnLabel  );
    Boolean setVal = rs.wasNull() == false;

    if( setVal )
        setter.accept( val );       

    return setVal;
};
```

The compiler gives me an error:

> The method accept(capture#1 of ?) in the type Consumer
>   is not applicable for the arguments (String).

It seems like I'm forced to use one of same types of any of my parameters or return type (if I put `Consumer<R>` it works just fine, but I have to return the value each time).

I've searched this site an the Internet, and I can't find any examples of this.

Comment: I'm having difficulties understanding what is your real target. Could you maybe explain a little bit better what you want do do? Maybe add an usage example

Comment: Why are you declaring all the generic type variables (`P1, P2, C1, R`) when you aren't even using them? You are describing what's happening but not really making it clear what you are actually trying to achieve.